# Pushing a Django application to pivotal (Cloud Foundry)

Tags: django, cloud-foundry

Pushing a Django app to pivotal (Cloud Foundry), it fails at the last stage; it couldn't write proper Procfile.

I didn't find any tutorials about pushing a Django app to Cloud Foundry. How can I do it? (I'll show logs.)

Comment: [Welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to Stack Overflow, You many need to show what you tried, and what errors you get? See [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make the question more legible

Comment: Check out this sample django app -> https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/pong_matcher_django

Answer (score 0):

Django is a framework build on Python. To push your Django app to cloud foundry, you may have to deploy a [Python Buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack) first. You can then try deploying your app with this buildpack identified in the app manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Tutorial](https://banck.net/2014/12/deploying-a-django-application-to-cloud-foundry/).

Happy Coding